# Serializing a fixed buffer in C#

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization

Is it possible to serialize a fixed buffer in C#? I am using .net binary serialization.

```
[Serializable]
public unsafe struct MyStruct
{
   public fixed int MyArray[10];
}
```

To overcome this, one option was to ignore the fixed buffer and create a property:

```
[Serializable]
public unsafe struct MyStruct
{
   [field: NonSerialized]
   public fixed int MyArray[10];

   public string MyArrayCsv
   {
      get { // populate string from array... }
      set { // populate array from string... }
   }
}
```

This works well for Xml serialization, but binary serialization ignores properties. Any idea on how to binary serialize fixed buffers?

Comment: This is really a serializer-specific question. However, it is pretty rare for serializers to *explicitly consider* `fixed` buffers. What serializer are you using? Do you have free range over choice of serializer?

Comment: You have to implement ISerializable.  Do also include the array size in the serialized data (use private const) since it is so dangerous.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't use [BinaryFormatter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter(v=vs.110).aspx)?

But here is possible solutions(safe and unsafe):

```
using System.IO;
using System;

public class UnsafeAndBinaryWriter
{
    public unsafe static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        Console.WriteLine("Hex buffer(unsafe): {0}", BitConverter.ToString(SerializeUnsafe(arr)));
        Console.WriteLine("Hex buffer        : {0}", BitConverter.ToString(Serialize(arr)));
    }
    private static unsafe byte[] SerializeUnsafe(int[] arr)
    {
        int totalSize = arr.Length * sizeof(int);
        byte[] resultBuffer = new byte[totalSize];
        // Of course you can do it without unsafe magic :)
        fixed (int* p = (&arr[0])) {
            byte* ptr = (byte*)p;
            for (int i = 0; i < totalSize; i++, ptr++)
                resultBuffer[i] = *ptr;
        }
        return resultBuffer;
    }
    private static byte[] Serialize(int[] arr)
    {
        byte[] resultBuffer = null;
        // Stream for storing result
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream()) {
            using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(stream)) {
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
                    bw.Write(arr[i]);
            }
            resultBuffer = stream.ToArray();
        }
        return resultBuffer;
    }
}
```